# Playing music throughout a flash video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How would I play an audio file throughout the entire clip that I am making?
It is a recording of myself narrating a video, so it has to start as soon as the video star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import to the Library, drag to the stage. Make sure there are enough frames to play the whole thing.

Comment: Okay, so I imported the WAV. file into flash and attached it to the first frame.  It is timed amazingly, but there was a DRASTIC degradation in quality.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Vote for my answer and I'll tell you...jk

Comment: If you right click on the item in the library, and choose properties, there are some options for compression. By default, I think flash imports at 16kbps which is pretty bad, but small. I would change it to mp3 and set the rate to the lowest value you think sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

There are timing issues with this.
Video buffering and audio buffering could potently make them out of sink with each other.
Best bet is to edit the video clip and overlay the audio.;
or import them into the fla and have one giant swf at the end.